# Apache Airflow Error Running DAG (ERROR - [Errno 2] No such file or directory)

Tags: python, airflow

I'm trying to discover why we are getting this error. Is it a missing dependency? A version problem? Why is this happening with just this one DAG and not the others?

The error is:

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: /home/airflow/composer_kube_config`

Here's our DAG:

```
import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.contrib.operators.kubernetes_pod_operator import KubernetesPodOperator
from airflow.contrib.kubernetes.secret import Secret
from airflow.contrib.kubernetes.volume import Volume
from airflow.contrib.kubernetes.volume_mount import VolumeMount
# from airflow.contrib.kubernetes.pod import Port

from utils.constants import DEFAULT_ARGS, DUMB_BUCKET, SCHEMA_BUCKET, PROJECT, \
    CLOUD_COMPOSER_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_SECRET, STAGING_BUCKET

volume_mount = VolumeMount(
    'secret',
    mount_path='/etc/secret',
    sub_path=None,
    read_only=True
)
volume_config= { 'persistentVolumeClaim': { 'claimName': 'all-ftp' } }
volume = Volume(name='secret', configs=volume_config)

with DAG( 'ftp_file_poller', schedule_interval="55 6 * * *", start_date=datetime.datetime(2020,7,1) ) as dag:
    poller = KubernetesPodOperator(
        secrets=[CLOUD_COMPOSER_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_SECRET],
        task_id='ftp-file-poller',
        name='ftp-polling',
        cmds=['ftp-poller'],
        namespace='default',
        image='us.gcr.io/<our gcp project>/ftp-poller:v7',
        is_delete_operator_pod=True,
        get_logs=True,
        volumes=[volume],
        volume_mounts=[volume_mount]
    )
    poller.doc = """
    about this DAG info
    """
```

Here's a quote I found in the docs about this file:

```
  # Only name, namespace, image, and task_id are required to create a
  # KubernetesPodOperator. In Cloud Composer, currently the operator defaults
  # to using the config file found at `/home/airflow/composer_kube_config if
  # no `config_file` parameter is specified. By default it will contain the
  # credentials for Cloud Composer's Google Kubernetes Engine cluster that is
  # created upon environment creation.
```

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by adding the DEFAULT_ARGS constant to the DAG definition like so:

```
with DAG(dag_id='ftp_file_poller',
        schedule_interval="55 6 * * *",
        start_date=datetime.datetime(2020,7,1),
        default_args=DEFAULT_ARGS) as dag:
```